# What is the in-game laguage settings in International Pro Tournaments?

Tags: league-of-legends

just out of curiosity, does anyone know what the in-game language setting for Pro-gamer's International Tournament set as?

I'm just wondering since there are pro gamers from all around the globe for international competition and they will not be speaking the same languages.

Of course, I'm aware that as a pro gamer, one should always know any detail information of certain champs skill description, effect, and item descriptions and whatnot.

But I'm just curious of how the in-game settings work for the League International Tournaments.

Comment: English, the language it was written in.

Comment: Language is set on a per-client basis, is it not? I would imagine it would have to be client-side since players on european servers don't all speak the same language.

Comment: Official Tournaments use the TOURNAMENT CLIENT. Downvoters and @VanBuzzKill most likely did not know that and as such goes to show why the downvoters are in the wrong. There is legitimancy to this question.

Comment: Oak is correct. The Tournament's are usually on a stable, fully tested version of it's own client that is stripped down to avoid unnecessary bugs.

Comment: Isn't OP asking what the *language* is in the client? It's whatever the player wants it to be. League has been translated to a dozen languages, they can just pick one of them when they're starting the tournament client.

Comment: For example, I can start my client right now and switch my language settings to German before I start up the game and the entire game will be in German.

Comment: @nukeforum As Oak already noted, the client you use is not the tournament client.  I don't see why that client wouldn't have multiple language support as well, but it's still a fair question.

Comment: @Namfuak The language isn't built into the client. The client uses resource files to fill in the words or play sounds. The resource files can be whatever you want them to be. The fact that it is the tournament client shouldn't change this.

Answer (score 3):

Both, players and commentators, are set on a by client basis. If you take example on the LCS, in the post game victories, you can see that some of the imported players may have their client set in Korean or Chinese.

The same goes with the Spectator clients, the ones you see the action all the way through the game. In Brazil, they'll have this client set to the most talked language. Of course, there is not only one client linked to the game showed. There is at least 2 (for the picture in picture).

Now that this is clarified, in LoL internationnal games, the player's client will be set to what they wish. The spectator client is not unique as we said. Usually, there will be several languages that will be available for display with different "cameramen" just like an hockey game with different HUD for the different channels.

For how much different languages are available, I could not answer this part.

Comment: Commentators are also logged in to the client?

Comment: Well unless they switched their whole system just for tournaments, they are logged just like in a custom game except they have an unlimited number of spectator slots.

Back in the early days of the LCS, they had some technical issue and showed the LoL client with the list of spectators getting off the window.

Comment: Now that's a fun bit of trivia =)